# How to check whether T is an aggregate type?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++14, template-meta-programming, type-traits

I know about `std::is_pod`. But it checks more than just aggregate types. Or, is `std::is_pod` just the best we can do?

Basically, I want to write a function template for [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/117744/70823):

```
template <typename T>
aggregate_wrapper<T> wrap(T&& x);
```

which is only enabled when `T` is an aggregate type.

Comment: I can't think of any practical application of an `is_aggregate`. E.g. it doesn't help with serialization.

Comment: If you're looking for the type trait that tells you when e.g. `memcpy` is safe, then you want [`std::is_trivially_copyable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I want to write a `wrap()` function template for [this](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/117744/70823), which is only enabled if `T` is an aggregate type.

Comment: Do `std::is_object` or `std::is_compound` not meet your needs?

Comment: @mindriot No. It's about initialization syntax. Aggregate types support `{}`, but not `()`.

Comment: C++17 provides [`std::is_aggregate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_aggregate).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to synthesize an `is_aggregate` template. The rules for whether something participates in aggregate initialization cannot be detected by C++14 metaprogramming techniques (they would require reflection support).

The general reason for not having this is the lack of an explicit need. Even in the case of [your wrapper](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/117744/aggregate-wrapper), there's little *harm* in applying it to non-aggregate types, since uniform initialization syntax can be applied to non-aggregates. You'll make all conversions non-`explicit`, but that's something which can be fixed via clever metaprogramming/`enable_if` gymnastics.

The most useful place for such a thing would be in `allocator::construct`, which would allow you to use aggregate initialization to construct the object if `T` were an aggregate, while using direct constructor calls otherwise (to dodge the "not uniform" part of uniform initialization).

Comment: After a second thought, writing a `wrap()` like this may not be a good idea. Given an aggregate, you can't really tell whether the user wants to make an  `aggregate_wrapper` or something else with just `wrap(x)` .