# type traits for aggregates

Tags: c++, c++14, type-traits, aggregate-initialization

According with [8.5.1/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr#1) of the working draft, an *aggregate* is *an array or a class with no user-provided constructors, no private or protected non-static data members, no base classes, and no virtual functions*.

Is there a way or trait to detect such a feature in a type?
As an example, as `is_polymorphic` does for a class and so on.
Something like a type for which `is_aggregate<T>::value` is true if `T` is an aggregate, `false` otherwise.

I guess it could be defined using `is_array` and... what else? Not sure about that, unfortunately.
There exists at least a way to define a type like this one?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-proposals/L-2YY4zbgmU

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34994364/how-to-check-whether-t-is-an-aggregate-type

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm voting to close the question, I didn't find it, I don't know why. Sorry. *EDIT* I voted to close the question. My fault. :-)

Comment: @skypjack No problem.  I didn't exactly see it as a dupe so I just wanted to make you aware of it.

Comment: @NathanOliver That's why I apologized and said _thank you_. It replies to the question indeed. I missed it despite I searched for it and to close the question was a duty. :-) ..  Thank you again.